Keycloak, cannot add user roles to the id/ access token, version 25.0.0





I don't see the user specified client roles added to the id token in the latest version as well. They mentioned it was fixed (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14617)
Role added to user as well:

Can someone confirm, are we able to add user roles to the id token..
Also in 25 version, i don't see Attributes tab for a User

Tried both on docker image and local installation for the same version
Even I don't see roles added to access token.
Same for password grant as well.
Have I missed anything?

Adding mapper to the client roles and realm roles,

I can now see the client roles

When I added mapper and role scope within each client it worked. Adding in client scope tab did not work.

Scope: added roles again.

Now going to evaluate tab within the client, i don't see the client roles. 
